# How to style or avoid multiple function return checks in a block of code

Tags: c, design-patterns, coding-style

Lots of times in my code I have blocks like this:

```
close(READ);
dup(fd[READ]);
close(fd[READ]);
execl("ay", "bee", NULL);
```

How can I avoid a bunch of

```
if (close(READ) == -1) {
    perror("close");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
...repeat for each function...
```

Or what is a good practice to deal with this?

I tried something like this:

```
void test_returns(int result, char * err) {
    if (result == -1) {
        perror(err);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

/* code */
test_returns(close(READ), "close");
test_returns(dup(fd[READ]), "dup");
test_returns(close(fd[READ]), "close");
test_returns(execl("ay", "bee", NULL), "execl");
```

But I think this is not a good way to go about it. What is a good solution for this?

Comment: Usually you don't want to exit right away if an error occurs but just return an error code from the current function. In either case, you can't avoid the `if`s (except with macros, but this could get really ugly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to this problem so far was encountered by chance here: http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/learn-c-the-hard-waych21.html#x26-10500021

I think it's much cleaner that macros for each function as suggested in the other answers. Maybe someone has a better solution but for now this is what I'll be using.